# Checking a string within an array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am using a simple error handling and I think I have everything else right, how would I make the **if** statement check to see if the **value** is equal to this array?

```
String[] values = { "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K" };

public String Value
{
    get
    {
        return _value;
    }

    set
    {
        if (value != values)
            throw new Exception("Invalid Card Value");
        _value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to see if the given value is *in* the array?

Comment: "how would I make the if statement check to see if the Value is equal to this array?", `Value` is of type string, it can never be equal to string array, instead you should search, if the `Value` is contained in the array like `if(!values.Contain(value)) throw new Exception....`

Comment: Side note - throwing a vanilla Exception in the setter seems like a bad idea. The caller then has to check the message to know how to properly handle the exception.  Either throw a custom exception that the client can catch and handle specifically or do validation at a higher level.

Comment: @DStanley especially considering how easy it is to do a simple extension of Exception.

Comment: @DStanley: there's also ArgumentException or ArgumentOutOfRangeException, which are descriptive enough.

Answer (score 4):

You can't just compare a string to an array of strings to find out if it exists in the array. You can use the `Contains` method to loop through the array and look for the value:

```
        set
        {
            if (!values.Contains(value)) {
                throw new Exception("Invalid Card Value");
            }
            _value = value;
        }
```

If you do this a lot, you could consider to put the strings in a `HashSet<string>` instead of an array. It's faster to check if a value exists in a hash set than an array.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.